# Ninject DI arguments passing to the unit test

Tags: c#, .net, ninject

It's my constructor with ILogger dependency

```
 public Book(string isbn, string author, string title, string publisher, int publishYear, ushort pageNumber, decimal price, ILogger logger)
    {
        Isbn = isbn;
        Author = author;
        Title = title;
        Publisher = publisher;
        PublishYear = publishYear;
        PageNumber = pageNumber;
        Price = price;
        _logger = logger;

        _logger.Log(LogLevel.Info, "Book constructor has been invoked");
    }
```

And my unit test with the attempt with solving it via Ninject framework

```
    [TestCase("9783161484100", "Some Name", "C# in a nutshell", "Orelly", 2014, (ushort)900, 60, ExpectedResult = "Some Name Orelly")]
    [Test]
    public string FormatBook_FortmattingBooksObject_IsCorrectString(string isbn, string author, string title, string publisher, int year, ushort pages, decimal price)
    {
        using (IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel())
        {
            var book = kernel.Get<Book>();    

            Console.WriteLine(book.FormatBook(book.Author, book.Publisher));

            return book.FormatBook(book.Author, book.Publisher);
        }

    }
```

And the question is, how I can inject the dependency and pass my arguments to the constructor?

Comment: Where is the setup of the kernel?

Comment: Come to think of it, you don't need to inject anything in this manner in a unit test. All you need to do is use a mock object as the logger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to inject stuff in the unit test. Just use a mock object for the logger:

```
[TestCase("9783161484100", "Some Name", "C# in a nutshell", "Orelly", 2014, (ushort)900, 60, ExpectedResult = "Some Name Orelly")]
[Test]
public string FormatBook_FortmattingBooksObject_IsCorrectString(string isbn, string author, string title, string publisher, int year, ushort pages, decimal price)
{
        ILogger fakeLogger = ...; //Create some mock logger for consumption
        var book = new Book(isbn, author, title, publisher, year, pages, price, fakeLogger); 
        Console.WriteLine(book.FormatBook(book.Author, book.Publisher));

        return book.FormatBook(book.Author, book.Publisher);        
}
```

That is not to say that the logger cannot be supplied by a kernel too, if you so choose, but you would have to set it up first and then get it:

```
[TestCase("9783161484100", "Some Name", "C# in a nutshell", "Orelly", 2014, (ushort)900, 60, ExpectedResult = "Some Name Orelly")]
[Test]
public string FormatBook_FortmattingBooksObject_IsCorrectString(string isbn, string author, string title, string publisher, int year, ushort pages, decimal price)
{
    INinjectModule module = ...;//Create a module and add the ILogger here
    using (IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel(module))
    {
        var fakeLogger = kernel.Get<ILogger>(); //Get the logger  
        var book = new Book(isbn, author, title, publisher, year, pages, price, fakeLogger); 
        Console.WriteLine(book.FormatBook(book.Author, book.Publisher));

        return book.FormatBook(book.Author, book.Publisher);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As already has been said, in unit tests you typically don't need to use container. But regarding more general question:

> How to pass my arguments to the constructor?

This way you can do so:

```
kernel.Get<Book>(
    new ConstructorArgument("isbn", "123"), 
    new ConstructorArgument("author", "XYZ")
    ...
    );
```